# Where can I find GIS data of Haiti Earthquake damage from the assessments made in 2010?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Where can I find GIS data of Haiti Earthquake damage from the assessments made in 2010? All sources seem to be dead links or PDF maps with no source data.

Answer (score 2):

The Haiti Earthquake Data Portal hosted at Harvard's Dataverse contains a set of geospatial datasets on the 2010 earthquake in both vector and raster formats.

https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataverse/earthquake_data

I have not personally inspected each file but they seem viable.  Citations for the datasets:

> Berman, Lex, 2015, "Haiti Earthquake Data (RASTER)",
>   https://doi.org/10.7910/DVN/ZT2DJW, Harvard Dataverse, V1
>
> Berman, Lex, 2015, "Haiti Earthquake Data (VECTORS)",
>   https://doi.org/10.7910/DVN/BAGUVN, Harvard Dataverse, V1